# Not using Tor message

Tags: anonymity

Why do I keep getting a message that says I’m not using TOR even though I’m on the iPhone app?
When I go to browse the web it comes back as not using Tor?  What settings should I use?

Answer (score 0):

There is no Tor Browser for iPhone. [The Tor Project suggests that you use the Onion Browser instead](https://support.torproject.org/tormobile/tormobile-3/). After you install that app, go to https://check.torproject.org to confirm if you are on the Tor network.